# button2 unable to use after starting a serial connection with button1

Tags: visual-studio, button, serial-port

I'm using Windows Forms
After starting my serial connection program using a button1
I'm unable to click on my button2 to turn off the connection.
Also I'm not able to exit the form program I have to close visual studio to exit each time.
My Code is as follows:

```
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms;
   using System.IO.Ports;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Threading;
   namespace Depth_C
   {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       bool IsClosed = false;
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
           comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
           comboBox1.Text = "SelectPort";
           button1.Visible = true;
           button2.Visible = false;   
       }
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, ThreadStart ListenSerial)
       {
           Thread Hilo = new Thread(ListenSerial);
           Hilo.Start();
       }
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
           serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
           serialPort1.Open();
           button1.Visible = false;
           button2.Visible = true;
           button2.Enabled = true;
           while (!IsClosed)
               try
               {
                   string AString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                   textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           textBox1.Text = AString;
                       }
                       ));
               }
               catch { }
        }
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           serialPort1.Close();
           button1.Visible = true;
           button2.Visible = false;
           button1.Enabled = true;
       }
    }
    }
```

How do I correct this what am I missing

Comment: This is a natural phenomenon that occurs because the `button1_Click()` function does not end in a `while(!IsClosed)` loop. Please recreate it referring to the article around here. [Serial Comms in C# for Beginners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners), [GUI based Serial Communication Program using C#](https://www.xanthium.in/building-opensource-gui-based-serial-port-communication-program-dot-net-framework-and-arduino), [Communicating ...](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/communicating-with-serial-port-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Thanks for info will try check and correct